# What is a free open source webmail software with pgp support?

Tags: software-rec, webmail, pgp

I've a virtual server not a ksm but with lighttpd and mysql and postfix. Can I use it to replace my existing free webmail and what is a good software? I also want to use pgp if it's possible?

Comment: What are your other requirements besides GPG support? There's tons of webmail applications available.

Comment: I'm new to gpg support and I wonder how it would work in a hybrid environement? I don't know much people using GPG and I wonder why the free webmailer doesn't support it because it's already 2013?

Answer (score 2):

[Squirrelmail](http://squirrelmail.org/index.php) has everything you're asking for.

[image: squirrelmail screenshot]

Has good [plugin support for pgp](http://squirrelmail.org/plugin_view.php?id=153) as well.

Answer (score 2):

[Horde's IMP](http://www.horde.org/apps/imp) features GPG/PGP encryption as well as S/MIME support. It's rather a somewhat more complex framework (in which IMP is just one application), but in my opinion, it has a fairly high quality standard and good user experience compared to most other open source webmail software.

Screenshot:

[image: Horde Portal Screen]

Answer (score 0):

Rainloop, hands down. Website [here](http://www.rainloop.net/). Screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: This is commercial software for which the standard version is not free, nor open source.

Comment: @anthon this software is [released under the GNU affero GPL and is free for non commercial use.](http://www.rainloop.net/licensing/) I believe that makes it qualify on both fronts.